# Timedelta in Pyspark Dataframes - TypeError

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on Spark 2.3, Python 3.6 with pyspark 2.3.1

I have a Spark DataFrame where each entry is a workstep, and I want to get some rows together into a work session. This should be done in the below function `getSessions`. I believe it works.

I further create an RDD that contains all information that I want - each entry is a Row object with the desired columns, it looks like the types are fine (some data disguised):

```
rddSessions_flattened.take(1)

# [Row(counter=1, end=datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 6, 9, 15, 20), end_id=2758327, no_of_entries=5, shortID=u'DISGUISED', start=datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 6, 9, 13, 59), start_id=INTEGERNUMBER, strDuration='0:01:21', tNumber=u'DISGUISED', timeDuration=datetime.timedelta(0, 81))]
```

If I now want to make a DataFrame our of the RDD, I get a TypeError.

```
df = rddSessions_flattened.toDF()

df.show()

# TypeError: not supported type: type 'datetime.timedelta'
```

(the full error message posted at the very end)

Any thoughts what went wrong and how to fix this?

- I basically rely on Spark to infer the schema; I would think this works as spark.sql.types module has a class TimestampType
- How would I define it programatically? The Apache Spark programming guide is not clear to me.

Appreciate your thoughts!

---

```
def getSessions(values, threshold=threshold):
"""
Create sessions for one person on one case

Arguments:
    values:      sorted list of tuples (datetime, id)
    threshold:   time delta object; max time of a session

Return:
    sessions:    list of sessions (SData)
"""

SData = Row(
    'counter'
    , 'start'
    , 'start_id'
    , 'end'
    , 'end_id'
    , 'strDuration'
    , 'timeDuration'
    , 'no_of_entries'
)

counter = 1
no_of_rows = 1
sessions = []   # list of sessions

session_start = values[0][0]   # first entry of the first tuple in the list
start_row_id = values[0][1]
session_end = session_start
end_row_id = start_row_id

for row_time, row_id in values[1:]:
    if row_time - session_start > threshold:
        # new session found, so append previous session
        sessions.append(SData(
            counter
            , session_start
            , start_row_id
            , session_end
            , end_row_id
            , str(session_end - session_start)
            , session_end - session_start
            , no_of_rows
            )
        )         
        # get the information for the next session
        counter += 1
        no_of_rows = 1
        session_start = row_time
        start_row_id = row_id
    else:
        no_of_rows +=1

    # regardless if new session or not: session_end reset to current entry
    session_end = row_time
    end_row_id = row_id            

# very last session has to be recorded as there is no "next" row
sessions.append(SData(
    counter
    , session_start
    , start_row_id
    , session_end
    , end_row_id
    , str(session_end - session_start)
    , session_end - session_start
    , no_of_rows
    )
)
return sessions
```

---

Full error message:

```
not supported type: <type 'datetime.timedelta'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/cdh/lib/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 58, in toDF
    return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
  File "/app/cdh/lib/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 687, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
  File "/app/cdh/lib/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 384, in _createFromRDD
    struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio, names=schema)
  File "/app/cdh/lib/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 364, in _inferSchema
    schema = _infer_schema(first, names=names)
  File "/app/cdh/lib/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1096, in _infer_schema
    fields = [StructField(k, _infer_type(v), True) for k, v in items]
  File "/app/cdh/lib/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1070, in _infer_type
    raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))
TypeError: not supported type: <type 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TimestampType` is not the same as `pd.timedelta`. The former is analogous to `pd.timestamp` The second have a analogous type in spark which is `CalendarIntervalType` but looks like the automatic inference does no work for you and it is not trivial to work with.
I would recommend, if possible, you to convert your `pd.timedelta` to seconds or milliseconds having now an `integer` of (seconds or milliseconds) and work with it downstream in application, as it is but easier to work with and still represents a time interval in your chosen units.